# undefined local variable or method `request'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My ruby version is 1.9.1. this is first project in ruby i am trying to develop.
i am getting the error 
"NameError (undefined local variable or method `request' for #<User:0x3ab7220>):
  app/models/user.rb:36:in`login'
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:7:in `signup'"

when i try to enter some details and save the records. Here is the controller class

```
class UserController < ApplicationController   
  def signup 
    if request.post? and params[:user]
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        session[:user] = @user
        flash[:notice] = "User #(@user.login) created !"
        redirect_to :action =>"home"
      else
        flash[:error]="Signup unsuccessful"
        @user.clear_password!
      end
    end
  end

  def home
    @title = "Bookshelf - User Home" 
  end
```

My signup.html

```
<div id="signup_content">
<span class="title">Sign-up for a BookShelf account...</span>
<% form_for :user, @user, :url => {:action => "signup" } do |f| %>  
    <%= error_messages_for 'user' %><br/>

    <div class="signup_field">
        <label for="user_login">Login:</label>
        <%= f.text_field :login %><br/>
      </div>

    <div class="signup_field">
        <label for="user_first_name">First Name:</label>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="signup_field">
        <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password Confirmation:</label>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>

    <%= submit_tag "Signup" %>
<% end %>
```

application.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= @title %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id ="logo_image">
            <%= link_to image_tag('main_logo.png'), 
            :controller=>'home', :action=>'index' %>
        </div>

        <% if !session[:user] %>
            <%= render :partial=>"user/signin" %>
        <% else %>  
            <div id ="user_menu"><%= link_to 'Logout',:controller=>'user',:action=>'logout'%>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <div style="clear: both;height:0px;"></div>
    </div>          
    <%= render :partial=> "shared/sidebar" %>
    <div id="Content">
        <% if flash[:notice] -%>
        <div id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
        <% end -%>
        <% if flash[:error] -%>
        <div id="error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
        <% end -%>
        <!-- <%= yield %> uncommenting solved the double rendering problem-->                       
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide us with the exact error message ...

Comment: The error is in `user.rb` line 36. Please post the source of `user.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, your error is in `user.rb`. You're trying to access the `request` method of your controller, but you can't because you're in the `User` class at that point. Typically the model layer (`User`, in this case) should not know anything about your other layers (the controller and view layers). The controller is intended to handle things related to the request and response. You may want to read up on [MVC in Rails](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/) or [MVC in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller).